# How to get the beginning and end of the day with moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to get the beginning and end of the current day (and accessorily of tomorrow by `.add(1, 'day')`) using `moment`.

What I am getting now is

```js
now = moment()
console.log('now ' + now.toISOString())
console.log('start ' + now.startOf('day').toISOString())
console.log('end ' + now.endOf('day').toISOString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

This outputs right now

```
now 2018-04-18T21:20:02.010Z
start 2018-04-17T23:00:00.000Z
end 2018-04-18T22:59:59.999Z
```

Since the times are shifted by an hour, I believe that this is something related to timezones, though I fail to understand how this can be relevant: no matter the time zone, the day in that timezone begins right after midnight today and ends right before midnight today.

Comment: the "Z" at the end of the time stands for "zulu" also often called UTC or Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). See my answer for how to display local time instead.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

It is giving you midnight local time, but you're printing it out in zulu time. Try using `toString` instead, it will print the time out in local time.

```js
now = moment()
console.log('now ' + now.toString())
console.log('start ' + now.startOf('day').toString())
console.log('end ' + now.endOf('day').toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to start with **Monday** you have to use this one `moment().startOf('isoWeek');`

```
console.log({
  from_date: moment().startOf('isoWeek').toString(),
  today: moment().toString(),
  to_date: moment().endOf('isoWeek').toString(),
});
```

Comment: thats not what was asked...